# Is it possible to limit the records retrieved from a GeoJSON file?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Is it possible to limit the records retrieved from a GeoJSON file?

I have a data file in GeoJSON format that my Leaflet page loads from a local text file and displays as a series of markers

But it's a lot of points, and I only want the few that should be displayed in the current bounding box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe it's possible to limit the records retrieved from a geojson file. A complete geojson data structure is always an object, so if you only fetched a part of it (for example using an http range request) then you would get an invalid json syntax - missing either the opening or closing brace and the json would not be parseable by the browser.

> I only want the few that should be displayed in the current bounding
>   box

OK so this necessitates having a spatial index on the server side, and generate the geojson on the fly to include only the relevant search results. In a PostGIS context, it can be done with a SQL query on point data something like this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ST_Contains(
  ST_MakeEnvelope(%(minx)s, %(miny)s, %(maxx)s, %(maxy)s, %(srid)s),
   geographic_coord::geometry
)
```

Where the minx, miny, etc. parameters are from the leaflet.js getBounds() function which returns the current extent of the viewer. But the implementation would depend on your server-side resources.

Comment: Also, this approach should only be considered if the performance of downloading the entire dataset is *actually* prohibitive. For example in a web app I wrote, there are > 100K records, plus a lots of metadata, so downloading the entire set was was actually too slow. Is IvanSanchez noted well, there may be other solutions with clustering or selectively adding data to leaflet.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the GeoJSON is an all or nothing solution

Answer (score 1):

> I only want the few that should be displayed in the current bounding box

Why?

Unless there's a performance hit, you shouldn't filter the results - when you pan the map, you'll have to manually recalculate the visible points again.

If there's a performance hit due to a large number of points, use some clustering/decluttering leaflet plugin first (these will prevent prematurely adding elements to the DOM, which is *usually* the cause of slowdowns)

If the reason is "the points in this area are thematically aligned" then the answer is [process them first](http://turfjs.org/) and show the results.

Comment: Why? ... it's the performance, my test set of data was fine, but then I switched to the full set of 18,000+ points and browser ground to a halt. Clustering ... I found https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster but won't this still involve loading the entire data set?

Comment: "Loading" a data set of 18k points takes practically no time. Adding 18k elements to a webpage's DOM does indeed take a lot of time (even more with Leaflet 0.7.x and internet explorer). Clustering will load the entire dataset (fast), compute clusters (fast) and **not** touch the DOM once per item (slow).

Comment: See also https://www.mapbox.com/blog/supercluster/ and https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4357

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to "clustering". I've used the plugin https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you could write a filter, here is an example using jquery:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Won't this require loading all of the points? I'm trying to avoid loading all of the records